# How does Nominatim assign points on the coast to a country?

Tags: python, geopy, nominatim

with the geopy package and nominatim I have already done the mapping of coordinates to country names. But I would be interested to know how nominatim handles coastlines. Some points that are close to land but still in the sea Nominatim assigns to land, for others Nominatim does not find a point. Is there a certain radius within which Nominatim looks for a point to assign to a place?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, to help readers Please add your effort and more detail.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maritime_boundary